# How to Secure Route using Vert.x Sessions

Tags: java, authentication, session, session-cookies, vert.x

I'm trying to secure endpoints using Sessions in Vert.x. With my configuration, Sessions are initialized and can be found as cookies on Postman, secure true, and the HttpOnly flag is true, but Session data is not displayed. Now I tried to route endpoints starting with /api/* to be unauthorised unless a session is found but each time I test an endpoint it returns unauthorised even when a Session is present. In one of the solutions I searched, I found that I needed to inject .handler(CookieHandler.create()) together with .handler(sessionHandler); as the vertx Session needs the Cookie handler to operate, but there is no import for Vertx CookieHandler on my project even when I have vertx web and vertx core dependencies deployed. Why is session  not found and session data not displaying? Here is What I have done

LoginController

```
@Controller
public class UserLoginController implements Function<RoutingContext, Uni<Void>> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserLoginController.class);
    private static final String CONTENT = "content-type";
    private static final String JSON_TYPE = "application/json";
    private final UserDal userDal;

    @Autowired
    public UserLoginController(Router router, UserDal userDal, Vertx vertx) {
        this.userDal = userDal;

        RedisOptions redisOptions = new RedisOptions()
                .setConnectionString("redis://localhost:6379");
        Redis redisClient = Redis.createClient(vertx, redisOptions);

        SessionStore sessionStore = SessionStore.create(vertx, JsonObject.mapFrom(redisClient));

        SessionHandler sessionHandler = SessionHandler.create(sessionStore);
        sessionHandler.setCookieHttpOnlyFlag(true)
                        .setCookieSecureFlag(true);
        router.route("/login")
                .handler(sessionHandler);

        router.post("/login")
                .handler(BodyHandler.create())
                .respond(this);
    }


    @Override
    public Uni<Void> apply(RoutingContext ctx) {
        LoginData credentials = ctx.body().asPojo(LoginData.class);

        return userDal.isValidCredentials(credentials)
                .flatMap(login -> {
                    if (login) {

                        Session session = ctx.session();

                        session.put("userId", credentials.getPhoneNumber());
                        session.setAccessed();

                        LOGGER.info("User logged in successfully. UserPhoneNumber: {}", credentials.getPhoneNumber());
                        return ctx.response().setStatusCode(200)
                                .putHeader(CONTENT, JSON_TYPE)
                                .end(new JsonObject().put("message", "Login Successful")
                                        .encode());
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Login failed for phoneNumber: {}", credentials.getPhoneNumber());
                        return ctx.response().setStatusCode(401)
                                .putHeader(CONTENT, JSON_TYPE)
                                .end(new JsonObject().put("Unauthorised!", "Incorrect Phonenumber or password")
                                        .encode());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

SecurityFilter

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class);


    @Autowired
    public void handler(Router router) {
        router.route("/api/*").handler(ctx -> {
            Session session = ctx.session();
            if (session != null) {
                ctx.next();
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Unauthorized: No session found");
                ctx.fail(401, new RuntimeException("Unauthorized"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you initialize your router instance?